# Is it bad to SIGHUP the init process (PID 0), and will it reboot the server?

Tags: linux, init

Background in two parts:

1. I have not tried this due to not having a local machine on which to try currently.
2. I've a hung, remote server where I can ssh-in, but have only partial sudo access (can send `kill`s, but that's about it).

---

With the background out of the way, will `SIGHUP`'ing the `init` (PID 0) process cause a reboot?

If not, is there a way of accomplishing a reboot without engaging the "real" admin? ie, I'm a delegated in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kill -INT 1` reboot the server properly.
Find on [link text](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r18581836-How-many-ways-can-you-reboot-a-Linux-server)

I just try and it works.
It needs root account to be active. Normal users have a "Operation not permitted", happily !

Thanks Google !

Comment: well, there you go - figures that my google-fu was weak today :)

Comment: I guess I'm still wondering how "safe" it is, but thanks :)

Comment: Safe ? If your account is safe, the reboot is safe (it launch the reboot procedure, no crash of the server).
The security here is on the root account (or sudo) not on the reboot action

Comment: by "safe" I mean is it going to result in a partial reboot / have to call a tech in the remote dc to hit the power button